# Аббревитатуры

Tags: общие-вопросы

Здравствуйте! Вопрос такой: если организация официально называется ЗАО Аналитический центр "Малотоннажное производство", то сокращенное название правильней бы писать как ЗАО АЦ "МП" или ЗАО АЦ "МТП".  P.s. Юридически еще не задокументировано. Вопрос в букве "Т". Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

МТП. А вообще, название органицазии (что в кавычках) пишется полностью без сокращения, если не ошибаюсь.

Comment: Надо бы сменить название...

Comment: "А вообще, название органицазии (что в кавычках) пишется полностью без сокращения, если не ошибаюсь." - Вы не ошибаетесь.

Answer (score 0):

Нет, в договорах часто пишут сокращенку, в скобочках

Answer (score 0):

Сокращенное название обычно вообще не использует аббревиатур для собственно названия - того, что в кавычках. А "правильно" то и только то, что прописано в учредительных документах. Это относится в полной мере и к сокращенному названию. Все остальное - неофициальные сокращения, в той или иной степени допустимые, в той мере насколько они понятны в разговоре или неофициальном тексте. Я бы здесь предпочел без Т.

Comment: Аббревиатуры в кавычки не берутся.

Comment: Если так забито в уставных документах, то не то что в кавычки, хоть фигурные скобки. Но здесь сам подход странный... Из подобных названий аббревиатуры вообще не делаются.